# JQUERY load vs get

Tags: jquery, load, get

I have this line of code

```
$('#findemail').load('findemail.php', {id: this.id, tabla: $(this).attr("rel")});
```

which loads alright the data in the anchor div. However, it turns out that I need to utilize that data, namely it displays an email address and I need to "grab" that email address and send it through a "hidden submit" from the webform to the mail processing script. That line above is sending two parameters, the ID and the tablename, that are used by a SQL query, which selects me the email I want to use, in the form of $destination_email

Someone told me that in order to do that, I just need to use "get" instead of "load" like here below, but putting together that I am a bit retard and that I have about an hour "experience"  with JQUERY I dont know how to benefit from that code. My webform is some hundreds of lines below in that same page, so I dont know how to fully finish that JQUERY code so that I can fetch it from my HTML form to forward it, as I said. Please, if you want to help dont just give me a hint, I still dont know the syntax of JQUERY although I am struggling to learn as much as I can. The code is nearly finished anyway.

The full code is here below. The first line does the load alright, it fills me a div box with that and that is all I need. But the second line, as I have explained, fetches an email address in the form of a variable, and I need to work with that, that is why it uses "get"

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");


$('#reviews').load('SendIdToDatabase.php', {id: this.id, tabla: $(this).attr("rel")});



$.get('findemail.php', {id: 'findemail', tabla: $('#findemail').attr('rel')}, function(data) {
      // data contains the response
}); 



  });
});

</script>
```

UPDATE TO 99,99% FINISHED CODE

HERE is what I have. It seems fine to me, however, hm, still is not sending that email away

only below the dotted line is interesting, the rest works perfect. Below the dotted line is the code that fetches the email. It does load it perfect, it displays it so as if hardocoded on the surface of my HTML form as alvaro@mygmail.com but there probably is very minor thing impeding that to be passed on.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


$(document).ready(function(){
$('a.flip').live('click',function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");


$('#reviews').load('SendIdToDatabase.php', {id: this.id, tabla: $(this).attr("rel")});
................................................................................


$('#findemail').load('findemail.php', 
                   {id: this.id, tabla: $(this).attr("rel")},
                   function() {
                     var email = $(this).find(".email").val();

                 });

          });


  });

</script>


<?php
echo '<div id ="findemail" class="email">';


echo '<input type="hidden" name = "country" class="email" value= "'.$destination_email.'"/>';

echo '</div>';
?>





<div id="form-submit"><input type="submit" id="submit-form" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
</form>
```

Grasping the idea from Nick

it can also be that the SQL query issues not just an email alone, but the whole

```
echo '"<input type = "hidden" val=\"' .addslashes($aRow['email']) .'\" class=\"email\" .>"';
```

=======================================================================================

So There seem to be 2 different solutions that you Brian and Nick are proposing:

NICKS

```
$('#findemail').load('findemail.php', 
                   {id: this.id, tabla: $(this).attr("rel")},
                   function() {
                     var email = $(this).find(".email").val();
```

AND THEN THIS:

```
<?php
echo '<div id ="findemail" class="email">';


echo '<input type="hidden" name = "country" class="email" value= "'.$destination_email.'"/>';

echo '</div>';
?>
```

AND THEN BRIANS:

```
var email = $('#reviews').html(); // this to grab the email
```

and here below embedded in my webform

but, is the syntax correct ? where is the start of the `<input>?`

```
$('#my-form').append($('<input/>').attr('type', 'hidden').val(email))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still get the data with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), if it was returned to load in your element, for example:

```
$('#reviews').load('findemail.php', 
                   {id: this.id, tabla: $(this).attr("rel")},
                   function() {
                     var email = $(this).find(".email").val();
                   });
```

The concept is pretty simple, if it's in the response, it was already loaded in the HTML of your `#reviews`Element, so just grab it from wherever it was in there.

Comment: I believe this code assumes a chunk of HTML is loaded into `#reviews` in the form of `<input class="email" value="val" />`, as `val()` is primarily used for forms. A more applicable approach might be to simply retrieve the entire response using `$('#reviews').html()`.

Comment: @Brian - It was an example of what i *could* look like, I thought the explanation was pretty clear...get it from the resulting HTML, whatever form it may be in...

Comment: Yes, you guys are right, actually I can see it displayed it on my webform interface, I see it but I cannot grab it because it is like display how can I grab it ? I tried to pick it up from my webform like this <input type="hidden" value="' . $destination_email . '"/>' but it is not filled with any value.

Comment: I understand. As the OP said he was new to jQuery, I didn't want him to get stuck trying to figure out why `val()` wasn't behaving as expected.

Comment: @Alvaro - Can you post what your rendered result looks like, at least the section containing the email?

Comment: If I correctly understand you , then all I need to do is actually put $email in the hidden submit html code because as I can see, in the function above you are creating one that fetches that email and puts it in the $email variable

Comment: @Alvaro - I'm puttig it in a client side variable, for the above code to work, all you'd need to do is add that `email` class to you're rendered input (or an ID, anything so you can `.find()` it, like this: `<input type="hidden" class="email" value="'.$destination_email.'"/>`

Comment: Alvaro: you will need to grab the value once it's loaded onto the page using `var email = $('#reviews').html()`, then inject a new hidden form field into your form using something like `$('#my-form').append($('<input/>').attr('type', 'hidden').val(email))`

Comment: The rendered result says actually   alvaro@mygmail.com that is what I can see on the interface of my webform next to the Text area, submit button so this is because the # is in the area of the webform. So it is kind of "I can see the returned result, but my input type hidden value = should be able to "see" that too and include it as a value to pass

Comment: wonderful Nick! I am going to work hard on it to get it, I should be able. Will let you know

Comment: @Alvaro - Ah I see your problem, that hidden input needs to have a `name` attribute, or it won't be submitted with the `<form>` just give it a `name="something"`, where `something` is the form variable your server's looking for.

Comment: thank you Brian, I am going to examine thoughtfully the solutions that you have provided. How can I give correct answer to both ? I want to

Comment: oh about the name dont worry I did have that and i tested that hardcoded values it would transmit so the problem was not there the problem was that I could not "absorb" the loaded result. I am going to try now

Comment: I have posted the updated code in full taking what you both indicated. I am pretty close to it, I know because it does display on my webform and there must be one catch that is hindering it from being forwarded